# Why does the routingApi.matrix() method in the HERE API sometimes not find the cost between two points?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, here-api, herepy

I am working with the Here API and Python (herepy) and I have had problems using the routingApi.matrix() method since running the code multiple times throws the following error. In particular, for the same set of Start Points and End Points, sometimes it manages to create the distance matrix but other times it throws the error at me.
I understand that when the function is going to look for the value to the JSON variable it cannot find the dictionary that I am asking for. But I don't understand why for one iteration I have no problems and for another iteration it gives me this error.

The distMatrixComp() and distMatrix() functions are arbitrary functions that have no problems

```
Start Points:  [[-36.62871, -72.07365], [-36.59533, -72.0858], [-36.8972043, -72.028369], [-36.62639, -72.09149], [-36.6089, -72.10252], [-35.96823, -72.33622], [-36.42341, -71.96235], [-36.41848, -71.97017], [-36.61557, -72.11887], [-36.14303, -71.8106], [-36.1414329, -71.827859], [-35.96311, -72.31443], [-36.61005, -72.1025], [-36.61525, -72.07426], [-36.6163286, -72.1227685]]
 End Points:  [[-36.5874, -72.11869], [-36.56707, -72.07326], [-36.2867395, -72.5440474], [-36.60889, -72.10185], [-36.74158, -72.46435], [-35.9665601, -72.3123652], [-36.60703, -72.10427], [-36.6094, -72.0999], [-36.5874, -72.11869], [-36.61266, -72.10245], [-36.46084, -71.72261], [-35.95813, -72.33583], [-36.60979, -72.14558], [-35.9686549, -72.3149309], [-36.623144, -72.124962]] 

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<ipython-input-27-1bccda51e23d>", line 1, in <module>
        runfile('C:/Users/bacheleonb/Dropbox/Python/Project Carterizacion/updateMatrixDistances.py')

      File "C:\Users\bacheleonb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
        execfile(filename, namespace)

      File "C:\Users\bacheleonb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
        exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

      File "C:/Users/bacheleonb/Dropbox/Python/Project Carterizacion/updateMatrixDistances.py", line 166, in <module>
        matrix = distMatrix(listCoordenadas)

      File "C:/Users/bacheleonb/Dropbox/Python/Project Carterizacion/updateMatrixDistances.py", line 96, in distMatrix
        solution = distMatrixComp(startPoints, endPoints)

      File "C:/Users/bacheleonb/Dropbox/Python/Project Carterizacion/updateMatrixDistances.py", line 27, in distMatrixComp
        modes=[herepy.RouteMode.fastest, herepy.RouteMode.car],summary_attributes=["distance"])

      File "C:\Users\bacheleonb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\herepy\routing_api.py", line 295, in matrix
        response = self.__get(self.URL_CALCULATE_MATRIX, data, RoutingMatrixResponse)

      File "C:\Users\bacheleonb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\herepy\routing_api.py", line 40, in __get
        json_data = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf8'))

      File "C:\Users\bacheleonb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)

      File "C:\Users\bacheleonb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

      File "C:\Users\bacheleonb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

    JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

```
def distMatrix(listCoordenadas):

    # Función Auxiliar
    def distMatrixComp(startPoints, endPoints): 

        response = routingApi.matrix(
            start_waypoints=startPoints,
            destination_waypoints=endPoints,
            departure='2018-07-04T17:00:00+02',
            modes=[herepy.RouteMode.fastest, herepy.RouteMode.car],summary_attributes=["distance"])
        return response

    # Función Auxiliar
    def grouped(iterable, n): 
        return list(zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n))

    if len(listCoordenadas) > 15:

        restData = len(listCoordenadas)%15

        if restData != 0:

            restData = tuple(listCoordenadas[-restData:])

        nColumnsGroup = len(grouped(listCoordenadas, 15))

        columnsMatrix = ["Group %s"%i for i in range(1,nColumnsGroup+1)]

        if restData != 0:

            columnsMatrix.append("Group %s"%(nColumnsGroup+1))

        matrix = pd.DataFrame(columns = columnsMatrix)

        for x in grouped(listCoordenadas, 15):

           comb = {}

           for y, c in zip(grouped(listCoordenadas, 15),
                           columnsMatrix):

               comb[c] = [list(x), list(y)]

           if restData != 0:

               comb["Group %s"%(nColumnsGroup+1)] = [list(x), list(restData)]
               matrix = matrix.append(comb, ignore_index= True)

           else:

               matrix = matrix.append(comb, ignore_index= True)

        if restData != 0:

            comb = {}
            for x, c in zip(grouped(listCoordenadas,15),
                            columnsMatrix):

                comb[c] = [list(restData), list(x)]

            comb["Group %s"%(nColumnsGroup+1)] = [list(restData), list(restData)]

            matrix = matrix.append(comb, ignore_index= True)

        nRowsMatrix = matrix.shape[0]
        nColumnsMatrix = matrix.shape[1]
        print(matrix)
        finalDistanceMatrix = [[0 for i in range(nRowsMatrix)] for j in range(nColumnsMatrix)]
        for i in range(nRowsMatrix):

            for j in range(nColumnsMatrix):

                startPoints = matrix.iloc[i,j][0]
                endPoints = matrix.iloc[i,j][1]
                print("nRow: ", i)
                print("nCol: ", j)
                print("Start Points: ", startPoints)
                print("End Points: ", endPoints, "\n")
                solution = distMatrixComp(startPoints, endPoints)
                #print(solution)
                tempDistMatrix = [[0 for i in range(len(endPoints))] for j in range(len(startPoints))]

                for k in solution.response["matrixEntry"]:

                    tempDistMatrix[k["startIndex"]][k["destinationIndex"]] = k["summary"]["distance"]

                finalDistanceMatrix[i][j] = tempDistMatrix

        distanceMatrix = np.zeros((len(listCoordenadas), len(listCoordenadas)))

        indiceX = 0
        indiceY = 0

        for i in finalDistanceMatrix:
            for j in i:

                tempX = 0

                for k in range(len(j)):
                    tempY = 0

                    for l in j[k]:

                        distanceMatrix[indiceX+tempX,indiceY+tempY] = l

                        tempY += 1
                    tempX += 1    

                indiceY += len(j[0])
            indiceY = 0
            indiceX += len(j)

    else:            

        distanceMatrix = np.zeros((len(listCoordenadas), len(listCoordenadas)))
        solution = distMatrixComp(listCoordenadas, listCoordenadas)
        for i in solution.response["matrixEntry"]:

            distanceMatrix[i["startIndex"]][i["destinationIndex"]] = i["summary"]["distance"]

    matrixRaw = distanceMatrix
    matrix = pd.DataFrame(matrixRaw)
    #matrix = (matrix-matrix.min())/(matrix.max()-matrix.min())

    return matrix
```

```
{"response": {"matrixEntry": [{"destinationIndex": 0, "startIndex": 0, "summary": {"costFactor": 2390, "distance": 33519}}, 
                              {"destinationIndex": 1, "startIndex": 0, "summary": {"costFactor": 346, "distance": 1916}}, 
                              {"destinationIndex": 2, "startIndex": 0, "summary": {"costFactor": 2259, "distance": 32941}}, 
                              {"destinationIndex": 3, "startIndex": 0, "summary": {"costFactor": 2090, "distance": 27661}}, 
                              {"destinationIndex": 4, "startIndex": 0, "status": "failed"}, 
                              {"destinationIndex": 5, "startIndex": 0, "summary": {"costFactor": 4485, "distance": 78916}}, 
                              {"destinationIndex": 6, "startIndex": 0, "summary": {"costFactor": 5751, "distance": 111151}}, 

                              {"destinationIndex": 3, "startIndex": 1, "summary": {"costFactor": 873, "distance": 6165}},
                              {"destinationIndex": 4, "startIndex": 1, "status": "failed"}, 
                              {"destinationIndex": 5, "startIndex": 1, "summary": {"costFactor": 2724, "distance": 43621}}, 
                              {"destinationIndex": 6, "startIndex": 1, "summary": {"costFactor": 4168, "distance": 80086}}, 

                              {"destinationIndex": 2, "startIndex": 2, "summary": {"costFactor": 3198, "distance": 62491}},
                              {"destinationIndex": 3, "startIndex": 2, "summary": {"costFactor": 3518, "distance": 69691}}, 
                              {"destinationIndex": 4, "startIndex": 2, "status": "failed"},
                              {"destinationIndex": 5, "startIndex": 2, "summary": {"costFactor": 4952, "distance": 100113}}, 
                              {"destinationIndex": 6, "startIndex": 2, "summary": {"costFactor": 941, "distance": 10104}},
                              {"destinationIndex": 7, "startIndex": 2, "summary": {"costFactor": 795, "distance": 8373}},
```

Comment: Can you share some code snippet how routingApi.matrix() is getting used ? Would it be possible for you to share the API as well ?

Comment: In the added code below, I added the full function. In particular, I understand that for the routingApi.matrix() method the maximum number of computation is 15x15 nodes, therefore, since I need to make matrices between more nodes, what I do is segment the computation from 15 into 15. And then I create a final matrix with all the 15 x 15 sub-matrices

Comment: So, when I'm iterating over this 15x15 nodes, sometimes the error above appears. But I run the code again, and doesn't occur

Comment: Please see the last code I posted, here you can see the response value of routingApi.matrix() In particular, some status are "failed"

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Start waypoints "List of waypoints defining start points of the routes in the matrix. The number of starts in M:N requests is limited to 15."
15 * 15 should work, but herepy is not hosted by HERE so can't really tell what exactly the problem was. It looks like the problem is timeout due to the spread of destinations.

Could you please try to use less nodes than 15 or you can try to use the Routing API directly https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/example-matrix-use-post-method.html